# Rerefence to a const char* array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am trying to avoid to repeat my code for 5 differentes arrays. I have 3 arrays (could be more in future):

```
const char *FirstlistOfOptionText[2]   = {OPT_1, 
                                         OPT_2};
const char *SecondlistOfOptionText[2]   = {OPT_1, 
                                         OPT_2};
const char *ThirdlistOfOptionText[2]  = {OPT_1, 
                                         OPT_2};
```

THe elements in each one will not be the same. Now they are because I just copy&paste them. Number of elements won't neither.

I have a function in which I want to print every element of a list depending on a value I give as parameter. Also, I need to print one of those elements in other color (all in white except one in green).

I just want to have one code for printing and selecting the color as I have right now. But I want to select the correct array before doing that. I thought about:

```
const char *listOfOptions[];
if(menu_t.first_level_option == 0) {
    listOfOptions = FirstlistOfOptionText;
}
if(menu_t.first_level_option == 1) {
    listOfOptions = SecondlistOfOptionText;
}
if(menu_t.first_level_option == 2) {
    listOfOptions = ThirdlistOfOptionText;
}
```

But I get some errors about storage size of 'listOfOptions' isn't known. Or that I can't use const char** for a char* or thing like that.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: "... code for 5 differentes arrays. I have 3 arrays..." 5? 3? thats a bit confusing

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the exact error message. "some errors" and "or thing like that" is a bit too unspecific to guess what is going wrong

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: btw. if your code needs to work only with C++ (it's one of tags), then you can use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: @Marqin: How so? The arrays have different dimensions. He'll need `std::vector`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Right, didn't noticed the number of elements information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you neeed to make listOfOptions a  char **;

An array of pointers can be referenced through a pointer to pointers (that's what the char ** is).

The size will be unknown to anyone using listOfOptions thus you need a way to determine the size.  Either terminate the list with a NULL pointer or you will have to use a 2nd variable (listOfOptionsSize) that tracks the size.

So the code below should compile (I opted for the NULL terminated lists).

```
const char *FirstlistOfOptionText[]   = {"a",  "b", NULL};
const char *SecondlistOfOptionText[]   = {"c", "d", "e", "f", NULL};
const char *ThirdlistOfOptionText[]  = {"e",  "f", "g", NULL};    

const char **listOfOptions= NULL;  // pointer to pointer(s)
int first_level_option= 2;         // some value for testing


if(first_level_option == 0) {
    listOfOptions = FirstlistOfOptionText;
}
if(first_level_option == 1) {
    listOfOptions = SecondlistOfOptionText;
}
if (first_level_option == 2) {
    listOfOptions = ThirdlistOfOptionText;
}

printem(listOfOptions);
```

Now for your printing function, it will get the pointer to the list of pointers as a parameter and and will look like this:

```
void printem(const char **listOfOptions)
{
     const char *word;

     while (*listOfOptions!=NULL) {  // while the pointer in the list not NULL
        word= *listOfOptions;        // get the char * to which listOfOptions is pointing
        printf("entry: %s\n", word);
        listOfOptions++;
     }
}
```

Oh, and welcome to C-Pointer Hell  :-)

Comment: I tried your initialization and i get this error: error: too many initializers for 'const char* [0]

Comment: I forgot to update. I got it working. I just remove the latest NULL element and set the size of each array. I have no problem with that because I have a variable containing the size of each array. Thank you!

Comment: glad to hear that

Answer (score 1):

`const char *FirstlistOfOptionText[2]` is an array of two pointers to char.

`const char *listOfOptions[]` is an array of unknown size with pointers to char.

`const char **listOfOptions;` is a pointer to a pointer to char and you can assign it the address of your list of options array:

```
listOfOptions = FirstlistOfOptionText;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> const char *listOfOptions[];
> ```
>
> But I get some errors about storage size of 'listOfOptions' isn't known.

The size of an array is part of its type. `T[1]` and `T[2]` are different types.

An array without a specified size is an **incomplete type**, and you cannot create an object of an incomplete type.

> Or that I can't use const char** for a char* or thing like that.

Yes, because those are completely different types. The first is a pointer to a pointer to a constant `char` object. The second is a pointer to a non-constant `char` object.

Your code attempts to treat an array like a first-class citizen which you can assign like a "normal" object such as an `int`. It also attempts to treat arrays of different dimensions equally. None of that can work. C++ arrays are more limited than you think.

---

The solution is thus to use `std::vector`. And while you're at it, `std::string` instead of `char*`.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#define OPT_1 "a"
#define OPT_2 "b"

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> FirstlistOfOptionText = { OPT_1, OPT_2 };
    std::vector<std::string> SecondlistOfOptionText = { OPT_1, OPT_2 };
    std::vector<std::string> ThirdlistOfOptionText = { OPT_1, OPT_2 };    

    int first_level_option = 0;

    std::vector<std::string> listOfOptions;

    if (first_level_option == 0) {
        listOfOptions = FirstlistOfOptionText;
    }
    if (first_level_option == 1) {
        listOfOptions = SecondlistOfOptionText;
    }
    if (first_level_option == 2) {
        listOfOptions = ThirdlistOfOptionText;
    }
}
```

Of course, this can (and should) be improved even more. For example, getting rid of the preprocessor macros and putting the list selection into a function like `std::vector<std::string> GetListOfOptions(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

To print a list of options you may use a template function that takes a reference to a static array as a parameter:

```
template <int n>
void PrintOptions(const char* (&listOfOptions)[N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        //actual printing
    }   
}

void PrintMenu(/* ... */)
{
    //...

    switch (menu_t.first_level_option)
    {
        case 0:
            PrintOptions(FirstlistOfOptionText);
            break;
        case 1:
            PrintOptions(SecondlistOfOptionText);
            break;
        case 2:
            PrintOptions(ThirdlistOfOptionText);
            break;
    }

    //...
}
```

The size of an array will be deduced by the compiler.